# Counterexamples to Kunneth formula in algebraic K-theory

Tags: algebraic-k-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety with an action of linear algebraic group $G$.  Theorem 5.6.1 in Criss/Ginzburg (*Representation Theory and Complex Geometry*) lists a bunch of equivalent conditions for when this space satisfies a "Kunneth formula:"

(a) for any $Y$ with an action of $G$, the exterior tensor map $\pi: K^G(X) \otimes_{K^G(\text{pt})} K^G(Y) \simeq K^G(X \times Y)$ is an isomorphism.

(b) the diagonal $\mathcal{O}_X \in K^G(X \times X)$ is in the image of $\pi$ for $Y = X$ as above

(c) The convolution in K-theory map
$$K^G(X \times Y) \rightarrow \text{Hom}_{K^G(\text{pt})}(K^G(X), K^G(Y))$$
is an isomorphism, and $K^G(X)$ is projective over $K^G(\text{pt})$.

Are there known examples of smooth projective varieties $X$ such that the above statements do not hold?

**Edit:** In light of the counterexample provided by Jason in the comments, is there a counterexample where $G$ acts on $X$ by finitely many orbits or less strictly, finitely many closed orbits?

Comment: For $G$ equal to a trivial group and for $X$ any smooth, projective curve of genus $g>0$, $K^G(X\times X)$ is strictly larger than $K^G(X)\otimes K^G(X)$.  In fact, $\text{Pic}(X\times X)$ is strictly larger than $\text{Pic}(X)\times \text{Pic}(X)$.

Comment: Thanks!  Followup: are there examples where G acts on X by finitely many orbits, or maybe less strictly, X has only finitely many closed orbits?

Also, maybe for future passers-by, this MO post discusses that counterexample in more detail and references the relevant Hartshorne exercises: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/244720/counterexamples-to-kunneth-formula-in-algebraic-k-theory

Comment: "... is there a counterexample where $G$ acts on $X$ by finitely many orbits or less strictly, finitely many closed orbits?" Let $G$ be $\mathbf{SL}_n$, $n\geq 2$, and let $X=Y=G$.  Then $G$ acts freely on $X$ and $Y$ with quotient a point, i.e., there is a single orbit.  So $\text{Pic}(X/G) = \text{Pic}(Y/G) = \{0\}$.  On the other hand, for the diagonal action of $G$ on $X\times Y = G\times G$, the quotient is isomorphic to $G$.  Since $\text{Pic}(\mathbf{SL}_n) \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},$ the map $\text{Pic}(X/G)\times \text{Pic}(Y/G) \to \text{Pic}((X\times Y)/G)$ is not surjective.

Comment: Oops.  Please replace $\textbf{SL}_n$ by $\textbf{PGL}_n$ in my last comment.

Comment: Oops again.  My example of $X$ is not projective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit.** User hic points out that with the first action I specified, there are infinitely many orbits.  So please change the group to $\textbf{PGL}_2\times \textbf{SL}_2$ with its left-right action.

The examples in my comment are only quasi-projective, not projective.  However, there are also projective examples.  Begin with the $4$-dimensional vector space $\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}$ of $2\times 2$-matrices, with its usual matrix product.  Let $\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}$ denote the associated projective $3$-space.  Denote by $\textbf{PGL}_2\subset \mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}$ denote the open subset of invertible $2\times 2$ matrices considered up to scaling. **Edit.** *Also let $\textbf{SL}_2\subset \text{Mat}_{2\times 2}$ denote the degree $2$ cover of $\textbf{PGL}_2$; the group of $2\times 2$ matrices with determinant $1$.  Let $G$ be $\textbf{PGL}_2\times \text{SL}_2$.*  For every action of $G$ on a scheme $Z$, since the character group of $G$ is trivial, the natural homomorphism $$\text{Pic}^{G}(Z) \to \text{Pic}(Z)$$ is injective.  This raises the question: what is the image?

The left action of $\textbf{PGL}_2$ on itself extends to a left action of $\textbf{PGL}_2$ on $\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}$. **Edit.***The right action of $\textbf{SL}_2$ on  $\textbf{PGL}_2$ extends to a right action of $\textbf{SL}_2$ on $\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}$.  Together this defines an action of $G$ on $\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}$, $([g],h)\cdot [A] = [g\cdot A\cdot h^{-1}]$.  This action has two orbits, the open orbit $\textbf{PGL}_2$ and the closed orbit is the zero locus of the determinant.  In particular, the closed orbit is a $G$-invariant Cartier divisor whose associated invertible sheaf is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}(2)$ with a natural $G$-linearization.*  The image of the natural group homomorphism $$\text{Pic}^{G}(\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}) \to \text{Pic}(\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}) $$ is the index $2$ subgroup generated by the class $[\mathcal{O}(2)]$.  Now set $X=Y=\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}$.  The Künneth  homomorphism $$\text{Pic}(\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}) \times \text{Pic}(\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}) \to  \text{Pic}(\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}  \times  \mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2} ) $$ is an isomorphism.  Thus the image of the injective group homomorphism   $$\text{Pic}^{G}(\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}) \times \text{Pic}^{G}(\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}) \to  \text{Pic}(\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}  \times  \mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2} ) $$ is the subgroup generated by $([\mathcal{O}(2)],0)$ and $(0,[\mathcal{O}(2)])$.

Now for elements $([A_1],[A_2]) \in \mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}\times \mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}$ with coordinates $$A_1 = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a_1 & b_1 \\ c_1 & d_1 \end{array} \right], \ A_2 = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a_2 & b_2 \\ c_2 & d_2 \end{array} \right],$$ consider the matrix product of the adjugate of $A_2$ and $A_1$, $$ B = \text{adj}(A_2)\cdot A_1 = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} d_2 & -b_2 \\ -c_2 & a_2 \end{array} \right] \cdot \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a_1 & b_1 \\ c_1 & d_1 \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a_1d_2-b_2c_1 & b_1d_2-b_2d_1 \\ a_2c_1-a_1c_2 & a_2d_1-b_1c_2 \end{array} \right].$$  Then entries of the matrix $B$ generate a subspace $U$ of the space $$ V=H^0(\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2} \times \mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}, \text{pr}_1^*\mathcal{O}(1)\otimes \text{pr}_2^* \mathcal{O}(1)).$$ The left, resp. right, diagonal action of $\textbf{SL}_2$ on  $\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2} \times \mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}$ lifts to a unique linearization of $\text{pr}_1^*\mathcal{O}(1)\otimes \text{pr}_2^* \mathcal{O}(1)$.  The subspace $U$ is a left-right $\textbf{SL}_2\times \textbf{SL}_2$-subrepresentation of $V$ that is **left trivial**, i.e., for every $g\in \textbf{SL}_2$, $$\text{adj}(g\cdot A_2)\cdot (g\cdot A_1) = \left( \text{adj}(A_2)\text{adj}(g)\right)\cdot (g\cdot A_1) = $$ $$\text{adj}(A_2)\left( \text{adj}(g)g \right) A_1 = \text{adj}(A_2)\left( \text{Id}_{2\times 2}\right) A_1= \text{adj}(A_2)A_1.$$  **Edit.***Thus, the left-right action of $\textbf{SL}_2\times \textbf{SL}_2$ factors through an action of $\textbf{PGL}_2\times \textbf{SL}_2$.  **Edit.**In particular, the nonzero element in $U$ corresponding to the trace of $B$ is invariant under $\textbf{PGL}_2\times \textbf{SL}_2$.* The corresponding zero divisor of this section of $\text{pr}_1^*\mathcal{O}(1)\times \text{pr}_2^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ is a $G$-invariant divisor.  Thus, the invertible sheaf of this divisor has a natural $G$-linearization.  Therefore $([\mathcal{O}(1)],[\mathcal{O}(1)])$ is an element in the image of $\text{Pic}^{G}(\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}\times \mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2})$ that is not in the image  of $\text{Pic}^{G}(\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}) \times \text{Pic}^{G}(\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}).$  Thus the Künneth homomorphism $$\text{Pic}^{G}(\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}) \times \text{Pic}^{G}(\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}) \to  \text{Pic}^{G}(\mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}  \times  \mathbb{P}\text{Mat}_{2\times 2} ) $$ is not surjective.

Comment: I like this example!  However, if I'm not making a mistake, I think $\mathbb{P}^3$ has infinitely many closed orbits "at infinity" (i.e. in the complement of $PGL_2$) i.e. there is a (trivial) family of orbits isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$ indexed by $\mathbb{P}^1$ (each orbit has representative a row echelon form matrix modulo scalars, and the singular orbits can be reduced to have zeroes in the second row and $\mathbb{P}^1$ worth of choices in the first row).  In any case this is still good to know, so thanks!

Comment: @hic.  Thank you for pointing out the mistake.  If I "double" the group and consider its left-right action (instead of just the left action), then there are only two orbits.  I have edited the answer accordingly.